# Inverse TruncatedSVD Not Giving Original Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, svd

Having an issue with TruncatedSVD not returning the original dataset. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.random_projection import sparse_random_matrix
X = sparse_random_matrix(100, 100, density=0.01, random_state=42)
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5, n_iter=7, random_state=42)

t = svd.fit_transform(X.toarray())

print(X.toarray())
print(svd.inverse_transform(t))
```

Expected output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Given output:

```
[[  4.53614251e-07   5.94986126e-09   3.56781739e-22 ...,  -2.72725083e-06
    5.13570405e-09  -2.15097572e-11]
 [  1.79826495e-17   1.72410454e-19   2.96469642e-33 ...,  -7.03013830e-17
    3.95942333e-19  -1.41558908e-21]
 [ -2.93753794e-02  -3.74847011e-04   1.49367361e-17 ...,  -3.65049683e-02
   -1.09142571e-03   3.85158003e-06]
 ..., 
 [ -1.55332590e-06  -2.01895537e-08   2.49596545e-22 ...,   2.73152004e-06
   -4.78520806e-08   1.67404008e-10]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -6.63184677e-03  -9.22742695e-05   5.28534360e-18 ...,  -2.32029752e-02
   -2.79132499e-04   1.01189068e-06]]
```

The documentation states that inverse_transform(): Transform X back to its original space.

However, in the above example, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Truncated** means that it throws away information, so the inverse transform is **not supposed to** give you the original data, only its approximation which can be recovered from the information stored in the **truncated** decomposition.

Documentation states that it moves data to the original space, not that it gives **original data**. These are two different concepts. And clearly what you got is in the original space (has a valid dimension).

In more mathematical terms, TruncatedSVD transformation is a function f which is **not** injective, there are many datasets that will be projected into the same representation. Consequently inverse_transform is not **inverse** of the transformation, it is just a transformation in **inverted direction**. In other words inverse_transform is such g that f(g(f(X))) == f(X), but it is not true that g(f(X)) == X. For a simple example consider functions f(x)=x^2 and g(x)=sqrt(x), they have the same property, f(g(f(x))) == f(x) since (sqrt(x^2))^2 == x^2, but for x=-1 it is not true that g(f(x)) = x, since g(f(-1)) == 1.